# SSRS export datetime different milliseconds on excel?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

[image]

The above is the Excel version that I've exported using SSRS, and have a look at below version, using same exact data, export to PDF:

[image]

Noticed there are certain records having a different milliseconds issues. Anyone have any idea how to fix it? PDF version is correct which align with the record from DB

Comment: Those are not milliseconds, but just seconds.  Could you add your data as it is held within the source table to you question?

Comment: @iamdave: Yes you're right, and I've found out the problem. Take second row for example, the data stored in DB is `14:02:16.899`, when we export this data to excel, excel will automatically round it up while PDF will round down and hence the reason for the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out the problem. Take second row for example, the data stored in DB is 14:02:16.899, when we export this data to excel, excel will automatically round it up while PDF will round down and hence the reason for the problem.

The solution I came up with was, on my query, format the `transactiondatetime` to have a consistent value instead of letting Excel and PDF rounding using their own mechanism.

Any other solutions or suggestions are welcome too